# Как восстановить версию python по умолчанию

Tags: python, ubuntu

Случайно изменил версию питона по умолчанию на ubuntu.
Было:

```
$ python --version
$ 2.7
```

Стало:

```
$ python --version
$ 3.2
```

Как сменить ее обратно на 2.7. У меня возникаю конфликты при обновлении или установке пакетов в apt'e т.к. менеджер пытается выполнить скрипт предназначенный для 2-го питона через стандартный алиас "python", а так как там 3.2, то вылетают исключения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в консоли

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 2):

В ubuntu/debian есть свой механизм для работы с разными версиями одних и тех же программ. Наиболее часто он встречается в описании инструкций по установке новых версий явы, но и для питона он также работает. 
Для питона, она работает он через:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

и делает, по-сути то же самое - меняет ссылку.

Хорошая статья, правда на английском, о том какие ещё есть варианты тут: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux